# Style block element where each line has vertical gap and, except for the last line, is full width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a title looking like this 
[image: desired result]

I've tried a few things on https://jsfiddle.net/hx4m9kfa/ but `display: inline-block;` is as wrong as `display: block` or anything with `width: 100%`

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}

h3 {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
</h1>
<h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset 
</h2>
<h2>
etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  
</h2>
<h2>
nonumy eirmod 
</h2>

<h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset 
</h3>
<h3>
etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod  
</h3>
<h3>
nonumy eirmod 
</h3>
```

I would prefer to have the entire title in only one tag (and if possible without JavaScript). But every result looking as the desired one will be much appreciated. Does anyone know how to achieve that? Thank you!

Comment: @OmkarVaity That does still leave him with ugly multiple tags.

Comment: You can use `span` tag inside the h1 tag and add background in it..like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hx4m9kfa/1/

Comment: @MukeshRam thanks for trying to help but that's not even close to what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
  text-align:justify
}

h1 {
    color:#fff;
    background: #888888;    
    line-height: 1.3em;
    display:inline;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #888888, -10px 0 0 #888888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #888888, -10px 0 0 #888888;
    -ms-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #888888, -10px 0 0 #888888;
    -o-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #888888, -10px 0 0 #888888;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 #888888, -10px 0 0 #888888;   
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam   nonumy eirmod lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It's 95% correct, the 5% missing is the `text-align: justify` .. thank you for this awesome snippet!

Answer (score 2):

So I hate to be the guy who offers a solution that uses JS or a CDN, but here it goes...

## Explanation

You're going to be hard-pressed [read: impossible] to do this without extra divs, or in CSS only. This is because when a browser sees you break a `h2` up using word wrap, it doesn't see it as seperate lines, it's still just one tag to the browser. Without writing your own JS, there is a free CDN called **[Lining.JS](http://zencode.in/lining.js/)** that appends the class `.line` onto each line of your paragraph. This allows you to target every single line in your tag.

## Solution

To start, this is my **HTML**

```
<!-- CDN to Lining.JS -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/lining.js/0.3.2/lining.min.js"></script>

<!-- 'data-lining' is Lining.JS's data reference -->
<h2 data-lining>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
</h2>
```

Here is the **CSS** I used for my example, you may have to tweak the width, but everything else should work out alright.

```
/* Splits h2 into seperate lines using clip */
h2{
    text-overflow: clip;
    width: 400px;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0;
    color: #444341;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

/* Target all '.line' classes that are created via JS */
h2 .line{
  background: #00FFCC;
  margin:10px;
}

/* Target last line class (change width to what works for your total width */
h2 .line[last]{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

You can check my **[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhp1jaex/2/)**. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: propably I will need to use something like that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've added a `<span>` around your text, which partially achieves what you are after. You can see it here (the `h2`) https://jsfiddle.net/hx4m9kfa/3/.

```
h2 {
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
  line-height: 2em;
}

h2 span {
  background: green;
}
```

The span adds the background while the line-height adds the correct spacing between the two lines. I do realize it doesn't add full width to the every line except for the last. But I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for helping! But as you've seen and said I also need that first line in this case to be full width.

Comment: One solution could be to add text-align: justify;  text-justify: inter-word; to justify the first lines of text, but it won't be exactly as you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the background-color of the page, you can use a few tricks.

First, apply a [`background-image: repeating-linear-gradient();`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients) on each heading.  This will provide the "spacing" in between each line by overlaying the `background-color` with repeating horizontal lines.  You will have to adjust the stops to account for varying `line-height`s.

Then, to keep the last line of each heading from being full width, you can use a pseudo-element.  Set `position: relative;` on the heading.  Absolutely position the `:after` but only set `bottom: 0;`.  This will keep it in the flow so it will stay at the end of the last line.  Set `width: 100%;` so it will always be wide enough.  Adjust its `height` to account for the `line-height` of heading.  Apply `overflow: hidden;` to the heading to prevent the pseudo-element from breaking out.

Again, the downside to this is that you need to know the background-color of the page or whatever the headings are in.

```css
h1, h2, h3 {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: orange;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#FFF 0, #fff 0.2em, transparent 0.2em, transparent 1.5em);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.8;
  background-color: green;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#FFF 0, #fff 0.2em, transparent 0.2em, transparent 1.8em);
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1.3;
  background-color: purple;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#FFF 0, #fff 0.2em, transparent 0.2em, transparent 1.3em);
}

h1:after,
h2:after,
h3:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

h2:after {
    height: 1.8em;
}

h3:after {
    height: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
</h1>

<h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod nonumy eirmod 
</h2>

<h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset etur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod nonumy eirmod 
</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for not giving up! I thought this is it.. it almost is! ...the last shouldn't be full width... but the idea deserves an upvote

Comment: @caramba Thanks!  But I still haven't given up.  I added a fix for the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS working solution, but unflexible. Multiple shadows for pseudo element `::after` of inner span (you have to add as many shadows as maximum number of lines you are expecting) + `overflow: hidden` for container.

Unfortunatly, it doesn't work for large texts.

```css
body {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, cyan 0, cyan 10px, yellow 10px, yellow 20px);
  }
h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
  }
  h2 span {
    padding: 2px 0 2px 0 ;
    }
    h2 span::after {
      content: ".";
      position: absolute;
      width: 9950px;
      margin-left: -9900px;
      margin-right: -50px;
      bottom: .1em;
      z-index: -1;
      line-height: 1.3;
      color: blue;
      background: blue;
      box-shadow:
        5000px -1.5em 0 blue,
        5000px -3em 0 blue,
        5000px -4.5em 0 blue,
        5000px -6em 0 blue,
        5000px -7.5em 0 blue,
        5000px -9em 0 blue,
        5000px -10.5em 0 blue,
        5000px -12em 0 blue,
        5000px -13.5em 0 blue;
      }
```

```html
<h2>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa.</span>
</h2>
```